# Simple lightbox wordpress plugin with wp_trim_words

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to combine simple lightbox plugin with the wp_trim_words function. There's a problem with the_content requirement so I can't get the gallery on homepage to work. I got this code

```
$content = get_the_content();
        apply_filters('the_content', $content);
        $content = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $content);
        $trimmed_content = do_shortcode(wp_trim_words($content, 50, '<a href="' . get_permalink() . '" style="display: block; width: 100%;">...more</a>'));
        echo $trimmed_content;
```

It shows the images from the [gallery=1,2,3] but the simple lightbox plugin is not initialized. What is wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`apply_filters()` returns data.  Currently, you're filtering `$content` but not saving the result.

```
// Before
apply_filters('the_content', $content);

// After
$content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
```